# Magento Admin After Login Redirect Back To Admin Login?

Tags: magento2, php, login, timezone

I'm using Magento 2.4.4, when I logged in to Magento admin it redirected me back to the login page without any errors. I checked logs but no errors in the log also, But I have 2 projects running on my local machine 1 project running just fine, and the other with login error, I've checked the log and noticed that the project which is running fine has this format of DateTime `[2022-07-05 14:40:56]` and the other with `[2022-07-15T13:38:22.603078+00:00]`.

If anyone had any idea please let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it might be because of the 2FA module because from version 2.4 onwards this module will automatically turn on. You can turn off this module and you can work normally

```
bin/magento module:disable Magento_TwoFactorAuth
bin/magento cache:flush
```

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading from Magento 2.3 to 2.4, 2FA doesn't appear on login I have to disable the 2FA module in order to solve this.